# Когда сколько "н" у краткого "растерян(н)ы"? А в приводимом контексте?

Tags: краткое-прилагательное, краткое-причастие

Землетрясение в Риме, шесть баллов.

> И на улицах привычный гул сегодня, но на экранах в глубине каждого
> кафе показывают страшные кадры. Плачут женщины, глядя на руины,
> **растерянны** мужчины. Больницы полны. Одного города – нет. Истории,
> конечно, поразительные.

Словарь меня только запутал, а второе "н" я сама пририсовала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лучше б не глядела. 8-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Плачут женщины, глядя на руины, растеряны мужчины.***

Пояснение

В написании этих форм наблюдались колебания, но сейчас ситуация такая:

1) Ответ Грамоты.ру  [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=растеряны](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Вопрос № 286259
 Сколько Н должно быть? Они растеряны и потеряны. (В эмоциональном плане.) По идее это должны быть краткие прилагательные, тогда две Н. Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

...Так как, судя по контексту, речь идет не о лицах, а о людях, то верно: **Они растеряны и потеряны**.

2) **Практика современного письма:** частотность написания формы ***они растеряны*** значительное выше, например: Люди были напряжены и растеряны.. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%C0%D1%D2%C5%D0%DF%CD%DB&p=0

3) В правилах Розенталя говорится **о прилагательных, которые ведут себя как причастия: одна Н в краткой форме и  две НН в полной форме.**  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62

п. 7. Примечание. Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя н (нн), а в краткой — с одним н, подобно причастиям, с которыми их сближает наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола: заплаканные глаза — глаза заплаканы; заржавленные ножи — ножи заржавлены; поношенное платье — платье поношено.

Я думаю, что к прилагательному *образованный* применимо это правило. От глагола  *растеряться* образуется прилагательное ***растерянный*** (хотя существует и причастие: растерянные игрушки). Здесь **нет перехода** из причастия в прилагательное по принципу образованная группа — образованные люди, поэтому и не соблюдается правило: группа образована — люди образованны.